# Concurrency with reading but locking with mutating

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, locking

I'm looking for a solution that allows multiple threads to read the shared resource (concurrency permitted) but then locks these reading threads once a thread enters a mutating block, to achieve best of both world.

I've looked up this [reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx) but it seems the solution is to lock both reading and writing threads.

```
class Foo {

    List<string> sharedResource;

    public void reading() // multiple reading threads allowed, concurrency ok, lock this only if a thread enters the mutating block below.
    {

    }

    public void mutating() // this should lock any threads entering this block as well as lock the reading threads above
    {
        lock(this)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Is there such a solution in C#?

**Edit**

All threads entering in both `GetMultiton` and constructor should return the same instance. want them to be thread safe.

```
class Foo: IFoo {
    public static IFoo GetMultiton(string key, Func<IFoo> fooRef)
    {
        if (instances.TryGetValue(key, out IFoo obj))
        {
            return obj;
        }
        return fooRef();
    }

     public Foo(string key) {
          instances.Add(key, this);
     }
}

     protected static readonly IDictionary<string, IFoo> instances = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, IFoo>();
```

Use

```
  Foo.GetMultiton("key1", () => new Foo("key1"));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a pre-built class for this behavior [`ReaderWriterLockSlim`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
class Foo {

    List<string> sharedResource;
    ReaderWriterLockSlim _lock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();

    public void reading() // multiple reading threads allowed, concurrency ok, lock this only if a thread enters the mutating block below.
    {
        _lock.EnterReadLock();
        try
        {
            //Do reading stuff here.
        }
        finally
        {
            _lock.ExitReadLock();
        }
    }

    public void mutating() // this should lock any threads entering this block as well as lock the reading threads above
    {
        _lock.EnterWriteLock();
        try
        {
            //Do writing stuff here.
        }
        finally
        {
            _lock.ExitWriteLock();
        }
    }
}
```

Multiple threads can enter the read lock at the same time but if a write lock tries to be taken it will block till all current readers finish then block all new writers and new readers till the write lock finishes.

---

With your update you don't need locks at all. Just use `GetOrAdd` from ConcurrentDictionary

```
class Foo: IFoo {
    public static IFoo GetMultiton(string key, Func<IFoo> fooRef)
    {
        return instances.GetOrAdd(key, k=> fooRef());
    }

     public Foo(string key) {
          instances.Add(key, this);
     }
}
```

Note that `fooRef()` may be called more than once, but only the first one to return will be used as the result for all the threads. If you want `fooRef()` to only be called once it will require slightly more complicated code.

```
class Foo: IFoo {
    public static IFoo GetMultiton(string key, Func<IFoo> fooRef)
    {
        return instances.GetOrAdd(key, k=> new Lazy<IFoo>(fooRef)).Value;
    }

     public Foo(string key) {
          instances.Add(key, new Lazy<IFoo>(()=>this);
     }
}

     protected static readonly IDictionary<string, Lazy<IFoo>> instances = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Lazy<IFoo>>();
```

Comment: Thanks Scott for the insights, I'm wondering what `ConcurrentDictionary` is about, let's say my sharedResource is a `ConcurrentDictionary`, should I still be using `ReaderWriteLockSlim`

Comment: Appreciate if you can please add an example to your answer if sharedResource is `ConcurrentDictionary`

Comment: If you have a concurrent dictionary get rid of all the locking and just use the dictionary itself. It already handles the locking for you.

Comment: my situation is tricky and since I'm new to .net I'm not confident yet, so let me explain the scenario, let's say I've several multitons I'd say storing in `key, value` pair, within function I call `GetMultiton(string key){..}`, within this function I check using `TryGetValue(key..` and if not found then I instantiate and add instance to the dictionary, this whole reading and writing in one function still requires locking? even if I'm using `ConcurrentDictionary`, because I'm reading and writing to it in the same block, and multiple threads can enter same block and overlap reading/writing.

Comment: Update your question with a example of what you are trying to do. Code is easier to read than words. Create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: You need to also add a little description about what the expected behavior you want in the edit too

Comment: edited, I want these two blocks, GetMultiton and constructor to be thread safe

Comment: Great lateral thinking, I didn't know about `GetorAdd`, last thing, is there an example on the web on how developers used to achieve this with simple `Dictionary` before `ConcurrentDictionary`

Answer (score 0):

The solution depends on your requirements. If performance of `ReaderWriterLockSlim` (note that it's approximately twice slower than regular lock in current .NET Framework, so maximum performance you can achieve if you modify rarely and reading is quite heavy operation, otherwise overhead will be more than profit), you can try to create copy of data, modify it and atomically swap reference with help of `Interlocked` class (if it's not a requirement to have the most recent data in each thread as soon as it was changed).

```
class Foo
{
    IReadOnlyList<string> sharedResource = new List<string>();

    public void reading()
    {
        // Here you can safely* read from sharedResource
    }

    public void mutating()
    {
        var copyOfData = new List<string>(sharedResource);

        // modify copyOfData here

        // Following line is correct only in case of single writer:    
        Interlocked.Exchange(ref sharedResource, copyOfData);
    }
}
```

Benefits of lock-free case:

- We have no locks on read, so we get **maximum** performance.

Drawbacks:

- We have to copy data => memory traffic (allocations, garbage collection)
- Reader thread can observe not the most recent update (if it reads reference before it was updated)
- If reader uses `sharedResource` reference multiple times, then we must copy this reference to local variable via `Interlocked.Exchange` (if this usages of reference assume that it's the same collection)
- If `sharedResource` is a list of mutable objects, then we must be careful with updating this objects in `mutating` since reader might be using them at the same moment => in this case it's better to make copies of these objects as well
- If there are several updater threads, then we must use `Interlocked.CompareExchange` instead of `Interlocked.Exchange` in `mutating` and a kind of a loop

So, if you want to go lock-free, then it's better to use immutable objects. And anyway you will pay with memory allocations/GC for the performance.
**UPDATE** 
Here is version that allows multiple writers as well:

```
class Foo
{
    IReadOnlyList<string> sharedResource = new List<string>();

    public void reading()
    {
        // Here you can safely* read from sharedResource
    }

    public void mutating()
    {
        IReadOnlyList<string> referenceToCollectionForCopying;
        List<string> copyOfData;

        do
        {
            referenceToCollectionForCopying = Volatile.Read(ref sharedResource);
            copyOfData = new List<string>(referenceToCollectionForCopying);

            // modify copyOfData here
        } while (!ReferenceEquals(Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref sharedResource, copyOfData,
            referenceToCollectionForCopying), referenceToCollectionForCopying));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Velery, I'm new to .net, can you please help in context of my code, interested to know your perspective

Comment: yes mutating is rare in my case and I've more reads, a code will greatly help

Comment: There is already `ImmutableInterlocked.Update<T>(T, Func<T, T>)` and `ImmutableInterlocked.Update<T, TArg>(T, Func<T, TArg, T>, TArg)` that you can use instead rolling your own. 
 Source code here https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Collections.Immutable/src/System/Collections/Immutable/ImmutableInterlocked.cs