# Thread safety a concern in this case?

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency

Do I need to have some thread safety mechanism in the following simple getter and setters for the Dictionary?

If required then examples for both lock and ConcurrentDictionary please.

```
    public virtual void Add(IFoo foo)
    {
        dictionary.Add(foo.name, foo);
    }

    public virtual IFoo Get(string name)
    {
        if (!dictionary.TryGetValue(name, out IFoo foo)) return null;
        return foo;
    }

    public virtual bool Has(string name)
    {
        return dictionary.TryGetValue(name, out IFoo foo);
    }

    public virtual IFoo Remove(string name)
    {
        if (dictionary.TryGetValue(name, out IFoo foo))
        {
            dictionary.Remove(name);
        }
        return foo;
    }

    protected readonly IDictionary<string, IFoo> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, IFoo>();
```

Comment: Why can't you write your own examples with lock and ConcurrentDictionary. This website is not a code writing service, you need to show some effort your self and we can show you what mistakes you made.

Comment: my first question is, is it really required to have thread safety in the above case? please advise me with some guidelines then I'll edit

Comment: how is this code used? Show us actual multi threading code you used.

Comment: it's a library and have unit tests for add, remove and has functions, I'm not sure how will it be used but will it require thread safety? Imagine it's a server side app, where millions of connections will be hitting server simulatenously and the app will be using this library for managing key, value pairs common for all users. One dictionary for all users,

Comment: if I convert this to ConcurrentDictionary will my methods add, get, remove etc. still be thread safe for all users on the server end, this dictionary will be a shared resource for all client users

Comment: @user2727195 Your `Remove` Method accesses the dictionary twice, so yes - it is a concern.

Comment: Thanks @ManfredRadlwimmer that's what I'm looking for from pro's, yes I'm reading first in order to return IFoo from function after removing, now let's say I convert this into a ConcurrentDictionary, will it be all ok or I've to lock(this){} for the Remove function?

Comment: in other words If I change dictionary to ConcurrentDictionary, will it cover all corner cases in Get, Add and especially Remove function

Comment: As long as your code calls multiple methods after another, using a different class won't change anything. Put a lock around every atomic operation and make sure you don't deadlock yourself. In case you don't have any experience with locks: Create a dedicated new object `private readonly object _dictLock = new Object()` and use the same object in every operation `lock(_dictLock){}`. If performance is an issue consider using separate read/write locks.

Comment: **All** of the above methods need locking.  Reading from a dictionary, e.g. with TryGetValue, is not thread-safe if other threads may be writing to the dictionary.  You can switch to ConcurrentDictionary as others have said, but be aware that the semantics are slightly different to handle concurrency.  E.g. when multiple threads may be adding the same key to the dictionary, you can choose if "first one wins" (GetOrAdd) or "last one wins" (AddOrUpdate).

Comment: @Joe if I change my code to use ConcurrentDictionary will I still be requiring lock in each function above (Add, Get, Remove etc.)

Comment: @user2727195 - you won't need locks, but you need to be aware that Add may throw an ArgumentException if another thread adds the key first; Has may return true, but the key may no longer exist if another thread has removed it.  Otherwise, you'll be OK.

Comment: @Joe I want the code to be bug free when it comes to threading, this is going to be used on server side where thousands of users will be calling these methods on this shared Dictionary, I want it to cover all cases, do you still recommend locks, can you please rewrite my code as an answer using ConcurrentDictionary, I need a perfect piece please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, here's a thread-safe version using lock.  Your Add method can call either `GetOrAdd` or `AddOrUpdate`, depending on whether you want "first one wins" or "last one wins" in case of contention.

```
public virtual void Add(IFoo foo)
{
    AddOrUpdate(foo);   // If you want "last one wins"
    //GetOrAdd(foo);      // If you want "first one wins"
}

private virtual IFoo GetOrAdd(IFoo foo)
{
    lock(dictionary)
    {
        IFoo result;
        if (!dictionary.TryGetValue(foo.name, out result))
        {
            // Not in the dictionary; add it
            result = foo;
            dictionary.Add(foo.name, foo);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
public virtual void AddOrUpdate(IFoo foo)
{
    lock(dictionary)
    {
        // Last one wins and overwrites if there is a race-condition
        dictionary[foo.name] = foo;
    }
}

public virtual IFoo Get(string name)
{
    lock(dictionary)
    {
        IFoo foo;
        dictionary.TryGetValue(name, out foo);
        return foo; // will be null if TryGetValue returned false
    }
}

public virtual bool Has(string name)
{
    lock(dictionary)
    {
        return dictionary.ContainsKey(name);
    }
    // But there's no guarantee it's still there when this method returns
}

public virtual IFoo Remove(string name)
{
    lock (dictionary)
    {
        IFoo result;
        if (dictionary.TryGetValue(name, out result))
        {
            dictionary.Remove(name);
        }
        return result;
    }
}

// Dictionary should be private, not protected to be sure a derived
// class doesn't access it without using locks
private readonly IDictionary<string, IFoo> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, IFoo>();
```

And here's a version with ConcurrentDictionary:

```
public virtual void Add(IFoo foo)
{
    AddOrUpdate(foo);   // If you want "last one wins"
    //GetOrAdd(foo);      // If you want "first one wins"
}

private virtual IFoo GetOrAdd(IFoo foo)
{
    return concurrentDictionary.GetOrAdd(foo.name, foo);
}
public virtual void AddOrUpdate(IFoo foo)
{
    concurrentDictionary[foo.name] = foo;
}

public virtual IFoo Get(string name)
{
    IFoo result;
    concurrentDictionary.TryGetValue(name, out result);
    return result; // will be null if TryGetValue returned false
}

public virtual bool Has(string name)
{
    return concurrentDictionary.ContainsKey(name);
    // But there's no guarantee it's still there when this method returns
}

public virtual IFoo Remove(string name)
{
    IFoo result;
    concurrentDictionary.TryRemove(name, out result);
    return result;
}

private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, IFoo> concurrentDictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, IFoo>();
```

Comment: Thanks Joe, is there more explanation for first one wins and last one wins.

Comment: "first one wins" means that if two threads concurrently call the Add method, then the first one will add the item to the dictionary, and the second will not.  "last one wins" means that in this situation, the first thread will add its item to the dictionary, and the second will overwrite it.  Read the MSDN documentation for ConcurrentDictionary.GetOrAdd if it still isn't clear.

Comment: `But there's no guarantee it's still there when this method returns` so what do you recommend to cover this corner, put locking in every function?

Comment: @user2727195 - Thread-safety is a complex subject, and writing a thread-safe application requires more than just using thread-safe components.  In this case, you might just get rid of the "Has" method.  If you want to know if an item is in the dictionary at an instant in time, then call Get, and check for null.  Another approach, depending on your application requirements, is to never remove items from the dictionary.  In this case, once "Has" has returned true once, you know the item will always subsequently be present.

Answer (score 0):

If your dictionary will be accessed from different threads then you should read the following about the Dictionary :

> A Dictionary can support multiple readers concurrently, as long as the collection is not modified. Even so, enumerating through a collection is intrinsically not a thread-safe procedure. In the rare case where an enumeration contends with write accesses, the collection must be locked during the entire enumeration. To allow the collection to be accessed by multiple threads for reading and writing, you must implement your own synchronization.

I suggest using `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>`as a thread-safe collection it provides methods that are atomic and thread-safe :

> All these operations are atomic and are thread-safe with regards to all other operations on the ConcurrentDictionary class. The only exceptions are the methods that accept a delegate, that is, AddOrUpdate and GetOrAdd.

check this link : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx

instead of using your own locking code, however you can use the `lock` statement
for implementing thread synchronization in case you want to use `Dictionary`, check this link : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx

Comment: "To allow the collection to be accessed by multiple threads for reading and writing, you must implement your own synchronization." does this apply for ConcurrentDictionary as well? Imagine if above dictionary was ConcurrentDictionary, will be using lock(this){} in each add, get, remove function?

Comment: locking can be used with Dictionary, but in case of ConcurrentDictionary it is not needed in most of methods, the only exceptions are the methods that accept a delegate.

Comment: oh your edit raised a concern, I had another question that used GetOrAdd and I never locked it, mind looking at it too to see if it's thread safe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41865146/concurrency-with-reading-but-locking-with-mutating check Scott's answer with Code #2 and #3.

Comment: These methods accept a delegate and as documentation tells : "delegates for these methods are called outside the locks to avoid the problems that can arise from executing unknown code under a lock", so in your method that the delegate addresses you have to provide locking mechanism.

Comment: Can you please edit your answer and help with the code, please use ConcurrentDictionary, also if you can help with the linked question using code, that'd be great and I'd accept the answer.